# Call stored procedure in loop within stored procedure for each record in a user defined table type parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

There is a stored procedure which has complex business logic with the definition:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UspCreatePayment(InvoiceId, UserId, ProcessorId, TransactionAmount)
BEGIN
// Business logic
END
```

This works well for single item processing but it has performance issues with middleware (.Net Core) when processing a batch(say 2000 items) because of the number of roundtrips made to the database.

I understand the ideal solution is to support bulk processing on the stored procedure but in the meantime, I want to reduce the number of round trips by posting all items in one transactions by posting a user-defined table type to a new stored procedure which will loop through the records and calls the orginal stored procedure UspCreatePayment.

Here is my user-defined table type:

```
CREATE TYPE typeCreatePayment AS TABLE ( 
            [InvoiceId] [NVARCHAR](36),
            [UserId] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER], 
            [ProcessorId] [NVARCHAR](32), 
            [TransactionAmount] MONEY
        )
```

New stored procedure signature:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UspCreatePaymentBulk(
                                @typeCreatePayment typeCreatePayment READONLY
        )
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @RowCount BIGINT;
      DECLARE @CurrentRow BIGINT;

      SET @RowCount = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                        FROM @typeCreatePayment )

      WHILE(@CurrentRow <= @RowCount)
        BEGIN
            -- call stored procedure to create payment
            --- How to call EXEC UspCreatePayment here?
            SET @CurrentRow = @CurrentRow + 1
        END
  END

GO
```

Comment: Can you please add tag for rdbms you're using?

Comment: Consider how should the main procedure handle errors while in the loop

Comment: you can cascade stored procedures, if that is  your qestion and maybe use a cursor for the outer loop

Comment: Why do you *want* to use a loop in the first place? SQL is a set-based language, so why not use a set-based solution?

Comment: yes, good idea (as a mid-solution), and yes- call it using EXEC UspCreatePayment + expected parameters, as you wrote in comments. and don't forget to set CurrentRow = 0. -- also as mentioned before, consider using cursor, it might be easier to fetch the parameters values.

Comment: @ThomA I understand that this is not the ideal way to achieve this. In the interest of business delivery time, this is a quick fix which does not need altering the core logic which needs huge efforts for testing.

Comment: You say that, but a quickly released process that ends up running *awfully* slowly could be far more detriment to the business than one that takes an extra day's effort and performs well.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already noted, ideally you would use a procedure that can handle the TVP in bulk in the first place.

But if you need to loop, don't use `WHILE`, it's just a poor man's cursor. Instead use a proper `CURSOR`. You want a cursor variable so it gets deallocated automatically, and you want `FAST_FORWARD`

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE UspCreatePaymentBulk
    @typeCreatePayment typeCreatePayment READONLY
AS

SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE
  @InvoiceId NVARCHAR(36),
  @UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
  @ProcessorId NVARCHAR(32), 
  @TransactionAmount MONEY,
  @crsr CURSOR;

SET @crsr = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT
  InvoiceId,
  UserId,
  ProcessorId,
  TransactionAmount
FROM @typeCreatePayment;

OPEN @crsr;

BEGIN TRAN;  -- do you need a transaction?

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM @crsr INTO
        @InvoiceId,
        @UserId,
        @ProcessorId,
        @TransactionAmount;

    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
        BREAK;

    EXEC UspCreatePayment
        @InvoiceId = @InvoiceId,
        @UserId = @UserId,
        @ProcessorId = @ProcessorId,
        @TransactionAmount = @TransactionAmount;
END;

COMMIT;

CLOSE @crsr;
```